# how disable an adf component based on iterator row size?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

I have an iterator in the bindings that has values which are displayed in `af:table`

```
value="#{bindings.participants.collectionModel}"
```

and I have another ADF component that i want to disable if the iterator has any rows

```
<af:selectOneChoice simple="true" partialTriggers="addproductbtn"
disabled="#{if the bindings.participants row size is > 0 }"
```

I have tried to make it as 
`disabled="#{bindings.participants.rowsize > 0"`

but it didn't work - the component was disabled even though the table was empty.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see `rowsize` as a valid EL property for ADF Bindings. See [this table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29049_01/web.1112/e16182/appendixb.htm#BABIGEIE) for reference of valid Iterator EL properties.

I think you can choose to use `rangeSize` or `estimatedRowCount`.

`disabled="#{bindings.participants.estimatedRowCount > '0'"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: `#{bindings.participants.rowCount > 0}` should work as well.